# Salesforce Custom Formula in Report

Tags: salesforce, formula

I am trying to find the # of days since last modified (Claimant: Last Modified Date column) from current date. Appreciate everyone's help!

[Screenshot of Salesforce Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b05El.png)

Tried playing around the custom formulas but I only get a syntax error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this FLOOR(NOW()-CLAIMANT_LAST_UPDATE)
just replace the CLAIMANT_LAST_UPDATE with the proper name